# If X and Y are i.i.d and positive, is Pr(X + Y < x|X < x) increasing in x?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence, monotone-functions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. random variables with support $[0,\infty)$. Is the function $f : (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by 
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \Pr(X+Y \le x | X \le x)
\end{equation*}
increasing?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3):

It is not. Consider $X$ and $Y$ concentrated at $2$ and $6$ with equal probability. Then

$$f(5)=\frac12\gt\frac14=f(7)\;.$$